# jQuery slideDown() returning is null error

Tags: jquery, css, tumblr

Helping a friend with his new tumblr blog.  Anyway I preface this with that because it might be of a controversial nature so please don't flame me, flame him.

He asked me to add some trickery to it, namely in the form of a link that shows an answer when you click it.  Everything looks good to me but when you click the link, the browser returns a  "$("#blah") is null" error.

Anyone have any idea as to why?

Check the code here:
http://conservativejesus.tumblr.com/

And click "Who said it?"

Thanks in advance.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

This is because `$` is being overriden by [Prototype](http://www.prototypejs.org/), which is also being included on the page.

Use `jQuery` instead, and it works fine;

```
jQuery("#blah").slideDown();
```